# rails if statement for nil = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

writing a rails app i have a if statement that first checks if 3 variables are not nil, and should terminate if any of the variables are nil.

problem is the variable_name.nil? syntax only checks if a variable is nil. how do i check if a variable is not nil? in essence i want it to return 'True' if the variable is not nil.

```
def my_status (product)
  product_sales = product.line_items.total_product_sale.sum("quantity")

  if (product.volume.nil? && product.volume2.nil? && product.volume.nil?)
    if (product_sales >= product.volume) && (product_sales < product.volume2)
      level1_status = 'Flipped'
    elsif (product_sales >= product.volume2) && (product_sales < product.volume3)
      my_status = "Flipped"
    elsif (product_sales >= product.volume3)
      my_status = "Flipped"
    else   
      my_status = "In Play"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If `product.volume` is `nil`, then it is `nil`. Your condition is redundant.

Comment: What three variables do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have to consider the possibility of any of the three variables being `false` (as opposed to `nil`), then:

```
[x, y, z].all?
```

Comment: product.volume, product.volume2, product.volume3

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an `if` statement on an initialised variable directly to return true if it is not nil (be aware that this also tests truthiness, use it only when the item cannot return false):

```
if variable1 && variable2 && variable3
  do things 
end
```

is equal in effect to this pseudocode:

```
if variable1 is not null AND variable2 is not null AND variable3 is not null
  do things
end
```

It's common in rails though to use the `unless` syntax for the kind of check you are performing, I would recommend this in your case:

```
unless variable1.nil? || variable2.nil? || variable3.nil?
  do things
end
```

Comment: erm `if variable` is checking truthiness, not whether the value is nil.  It's equivalent to `if variable != nil && variable != false` (since in ruby the only non-truthy values are `nil` and `false`).

Comment: Also I would really steer clear of the `unless` statement for anything more than a single conditional.  It can become difficult to read/comprehend very quickly when you start chaining `||`'s and `&&`'s to it (maybe that's just my personal preference)

Comment: I've added a comment regarding truthiness, but I certainly don't think `unless` should be avoided, It's a lot clearer than a collection of 'if nots'!